# Android JSONObject saying "no value for name", when the "name" item is definitely there

Tags: java, android, json

I'm using Android's `org.json.JSONObject` class, and it's worked wonderfully so far. But now I'm parsing a slightly different object, and it's giving me a `JSONException: no value for name`. But the name is definitely there.

I even logged a `toString()` of the JSONObject, and it's there.. Here it is:

```
07-28 17:29:47.281: D/asdf(1639): {"status":"OK","file":{"id":32707990,"icon":"removedforstackoverflow","screenshot":"removedforstackoverflow","name":"Testname123","created_at":"2012-05-23T22:42:55","is_mp4_available":null,"content_type":"application\/x-iso9660-image","is_shared":false,"size":155271168,"parent_id":0}}
```

Why is it saying it's not there, when it definitely is? Am I missing something?

Comment: You'd need to show your code. You have a `JSONObject` containing another `JSONObject` which is the `value` of the "file" key. You need to get that `value` as a separate `JSONObject` before you can get the `value` of the "name" key.

Comment: That was it. Fixed it by adding `.getJSONObject("file")` to my JSONObject's constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably trying to get the name from the root object. But name is a field of the sub-object stored under the `file` name.

```
String name = root.getJSONObject("file").getString("name");
```

Comment: Thanks! You were right, I was parsing the object _around_ the file object. Chamging it to `new JSONObject(string).getJSONObject("file")` fixed it!